# How do we write only fail jobs in a log when we use GNU parallel

Tags: bash, shell-script, gnu-parallel

```
parallel --joblog /tmp/log exit  ::: 1 2 3 0 
cat /tmp/log
```

Ηow can Ι use a filter to write only failed job in my load when using GNU parallel or is there a way to get only failed jobs from the above log? I'm a beginner for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parallel --joblog /tmp/log exit  ::: 1 2 3 0 
cat /tmp/log
cat /tmp/log | perl -ane '$F[6] and print'
```

Not sure why you need this, but if you are going to retry them, you may want to read about `--retry-failed --retries --resume-failed`.

Comment: I ran across this because a common case for gnu parallel for me is to run scans across large datasets looking for machine-detectable irregularities. I only want it to print irregularities (i.e. scan command failed on this file). It's a shame that parallel doesn't have this built in.

Comment: @ddulaney You are looking for `neno` (No error, no output): https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/tree/master/neno